# How to override/implement a module's hook

Tags: hooks

Is there a possible to override a module's hook? What I want is, write a `search__query_alter()` hook to restrict search results. But to achive this, I should write the hook in built-in module **search**'s .module file.

This way, I'm hacking into core drupal files, which must be bad. Is there a way to write the hook for another module in my **theme**'s `template.php` file or somewhere else, not touching the core drupal files? When I write `search_query_alter()` in my theme's `template.php` file it simply doesn't work.

From my question, you may understand I'm very new to Drupal! Thank you for helping.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You must create a custom module and add a custom hook function to it. The function name will be `modulename_query_alter ()`.  Drupal maintains a list of all included hooks by searching the enabled modules for functions following that pattern.

Instructions for creating one are [here](http://drupal.org/node/361112).  This is the basic means for introducing custom behaviors to your site. The hook system is discussed [here](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--module.inc/group/hooks/7) and you should look at using the hook_query_alter function [here](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--module.inc/group/hooks/7).

This will get you started and no doubt lead to further questions.

Answer (score 2):

You can override hooks, or use hooks to add data by creating a small custom module.
Start here on how to create modules:
http://drupal.org/node/361112

Basically then you add:

```
function MYMODULE_query_alter () {
  //put your code here
}
```

Where MYMODULE is the name of your custom module.